# How to append to R history file instead of overwriting?

Tags: r

I've put this in my `.Rprofile`:

```
Sys.setenv(R_HISTSIZE='1000000')
Sys.setenv(R_HISTFILE='~/.Rhistory')

.Last <- function() {
    if(interactive()) try(savehistory("~/.Rhistory"))
}
```

After quitting an R session, the history is written to the file, but the file is overwritten! How can I make R append to the history file instead?

Comment: How about using a time / date stamp to define the file name?

Comment: @mnel Thanks, I ended up doing that since that's more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After saving the history file you could use R's file read-write commands to append that history file to a different file, called whatever you like (`~/.R-ancient-history` maybe?).

And R has a function for that! Try

```
file.append("~/.R-ancient-history","~/.Rhistory")
```

in your `.Last`.

If you really want it all in `.Rhistory`, then do `file.rename("~/.R-ancient-history","~/.Rhistory")` after the append, which should do it...

All pretty well untested... That's your job!